# Simple past and present perfect- "One hour has passed." vs "One hour passed."

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-present-perfect

If I'm downloading something and it should take 2 hours to be downloaded. So after one hour for example I would say,

> "One hour has passed."

or

> "One hour passed."

and why?

Comment: ‘2 hours to be downloaded’ estu ‘2 hours to download’

Answer (score 2):

simple past is used to describe a situation in the past, whereas present perfect is used to talk about things that have just ceased.
IMO, at the time you make the statement, one hour would have just completed.

So, "One hour has passed." would be appropriate.